# What software to use for Application Planning/Modeling

Tags: application-planning

what to use for application planning/modeling? i want to create something like ...

**ClassName**

- Variables ...
- Functions ... what the functions do ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even Visio will do it.

The good old Rational Rose as well.

The class designer built in Visual Studio.

Or just a piece of paper and a pen.

Even better: just start coding. You can't plan what you will need in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for Unified Modeling Language(UML) software. I had to use System Architect in college. It seemed bloated but did produce the models similar to what you are looking for.

I haven't tried it, but you might take a look at [Umbrello](http://uml.sourceforge.net/index.php).

I use Visio, a white board, or a piece of paper anymore.